# How does flask know which function to call for a specific web adress?

Tags: python, python-decorators

In the populair web framework flask a basic web page looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

I am pretty new to python and i was wondering how this exactly works. I get that @ is a decorator that decorates the `hello` function but how does flask that is has to call the underlying `hello` funtion or even knows it exists, because the code does not run the hello function like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

hello()
```

When i am coding i like to know how something works before i just randomly accept anything. I searched my but off looking for an answer but could not find a pleasent answer. Also i looked in the [source code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py) but i was not able to find out how it works

So now the real question: How can i recreate something similair in plain python? So running a function without really calling it in the main code first.

Ps. Sorry for my bad english, it is not my main language.

Comment: Your question is not clear. That is what the `app.route` decorator does.

Comment: Yes i get that but how does it know to call the underlying function from what the name is nowhere else in the code?

Comment: the `@app.route...` decorator registers the function to the endpoint somewhere in the `app` object. That object is the one you do later on do a `app.run` to start up the server.

Comment: @DanielRoseman So now the real question: How can i recreate something similair in plain python? So running a function without really calling it in the main code first. (See end of story)

Comment: Decorators aren't magic; `@app.route("/") def hello(): ...` is just syntactic sugar for `def hello()...; hello = app.route("/")(hello)`. `app.route("/")` returns a regular function that can do whatever it wants with its function argument.

Comment: Put simply: `hello` is a callback function. *You* don't call `hello`; the `Flask` app does.

Comment: @chepner Yes i get it but how exactly?

Comment: The same way any function gets called.  This question is far too broad, because the instance of `Flask` itself doesn't actually do anything; it provides hooks for *another* process to call into once that process receives an HTTP request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`app.route()` remembers the URL (`"/"`) and the function associated with it (`hello`). Later, `app.run()` can query that association and invoke `hello`.

> How can i recreate something similair in plain python?

This program might give you an understanding of how `hello()` is invoked:

```
class Flask:
    def __init__(self):
        self.routes = {}

    def route(self, path):
        def wrapper(fn):
            self.routes[path] = fn
            return fn
        return wrapper

    def run(self):
        # Networking code goes here.
        # Suppose "/" comes in as a request, then this happens:
        self.routes["/"]()

app = Flask()


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    print("Inside hello")
    return "Hello World!"

app.run()
```

Alternatively, you can examine the `flask` source: https://github.com/pallets/flask  Specifically, `app.route()` is defined here: https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0.12.2/flask/app.py#L1054 and the call to `hello()` is here: https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0.12.2/flask/app.py#L1052

Comment: Thank your for taking the time to explain! I tested it for a little time and know now how it works. Now i can sleep peacefully :)

Comment: This is such a neat and well-designed example. Thank you!